# how to communicate between 2 web content viewer portlets in ibm wcm 8?

Tags: portlet, wcm

I have a requirement to communicate between two portlets(Web Content Viewer portlet) in IBM WCM.There are many ways for the custom portlets to communicate in between but I dont have any idea to implement the functionality for the ibm provided portlets(Web Content Viewer portlet).

Could any one guide me how to achieve the communication between two portlets(Web Content Viewer portlet) in IBM WCM 8 by providing some code snippets and required screen shots.

Regards,
Brijith

Comment: What type of communication you need? Standard ways are public render parameters and events, but to get custom events/parameters you need change portlet code, I suppose you don't want to do this.

Comment: Yup..Code change is not possible for Web Content Viewer Portlets,right? I want to pass some parameters from one Web Content Viewer Portlet to other Web Content Viewer Portlet.

Comment: Right. But how you want communicate between your portlets? You need pass data from one portlet to another? Are portlets on same page or different?

Comment: yes..I need to pass data from one portlet to another in same page.

Comment: What type of information you want pass to another portlet? I believe you showing content/component from WCM in jsr286 portelt, maybe it possible to do with javascript?

Comment: I want to pass a parameter from one component in one portlet to other component in other portlet.

Answer (score 2):

Web content viewers can broadcast and receive links to communicate with other viewers:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3JLV_8.0.0/wcm/wcm_config_delivery_portlet_linking.dita